# System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, casting, automation, mshtml

I am getting the exception below when casting an object as IEnumerable.

This is part of my automation project which was built using VS2008 and was meant to run on IE8, now I am trying to use VS2010 and run on IE9.

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.__ComObject' to interface type
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. This operation failed because the
>   QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
>   '{496B0ABE-CDEE-11D3-88E8-00902754C43A}' failed due to the following
>   error: 'No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))' and the COM component does not support
>   IDispatch::Invoke calls for DISPID_NEWENUM.

```
 HTMLDocument doc = some htmldocument
 IHTMLElement ele = doc.getElementById("some property");

 int iTab = (int)ele.getAttribute("someproperty", 0);
 object oTab = ele.getAttribute("property", 1);

 IEnumerable xyz = (IEnumerable)oTab;
 System.Collections.IEnumerator index = xyz.GetEnumerator();
```

Comment: It was working with IE8 and anyreason it can fail with IE9

Comment: I checked it again, same code works with IE8 but on IE9 i get an error.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty much as the error message says. The object in `oTab` does not implement `IEnumerable`. Whatever reasoning led you to assume that it did, is wrong.

Start by inspecting the value of `oTab`.

Comment: I am still not able to figure it out, any further tips.

Comment: Well, what is `oTab`?

Comment: oTab is an object which is stores System._Comobject that is being returned from getattribute. Strange enough in Ie8 otab is Ienumerable but same code when executed on a system having Ie9 oTab is not Ienumerable.Not able to get whta is the next step i should be taking.Thanks in advance,